# flowtype + vscode config file, flow.runOnEdit not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, flowtype

I use flowtype with Visual Studio Code, everything works other than the **run on edit** feature -- I have to switch tabs to make flow run again.

I tried with `preferences --> settings`, `"flow.runOnEdit": true`, but they worked the same with both true and false. not running when I edit.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

looking into [github issue 136](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode/issues/136), tried with

`npm install -g flow-bin`, and then restart VSCode,

fixed this problem.